# QGIS - raster resampling having no effect=pixelization

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, resampling, jpeg-2000

In QGIS I cannot make the resampling setting (changing it from nearest neighbour to bilinear or cubic) to smooth the pixels of Sentinel-2 imagery, both as jp2 or tif. If I export the image, convert it to png, georeference it, then the resampling works and the image pixels are smoothed out. Irfanview has no problem resampling jp2 or tiff.

I cannot find anything online describing this problem. Am I missing something that allow the jp2/tif resampling on QGIS?

[image]

Comment: More information on your processing steps, please.  At what point in your processing steps are you applying the "resampling setting"?  Is there a particular tool that requires the setting?

Comment: In this case there were no processing steps, I just drag and dropped into the project the true colour image that comes ready to go in the sentinel-2 image package. Once it is displayed, I go to "layer styling" and in "resampling" I change from "nearest neighbour " (the default option) to "bilinear" or "cubic". And nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an "answer" because I don't know how to put screenshots in a comment - but I hope this helps you.  I wonder if you have an older QGIS version where the resampling option isn't working correctly?  Anyway, at 3.14.16 the *Layer Styling > Resampling* setting works for me, as shown below.

The first image is a .tif drag-dropped into QGIS, then zoomed in.  The image is the USA FAA aviation sectional map for the Anchorage, Alaska area.  As you can see, the default resampling is *Nearest Neighbor*, and a pixelated effect is apparent:

[image]

Without making any other adjustments to the image, I then changed the resampling setting to *Cubic*, where, as expected, the pixelation is less noticeable:

[image]

Comment: Shamefully, that solved my problem... I had 3.12 and once installed 3.16, voila, problem solved. Thanks!